# Determinant of a 4 by 4 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose $(a,b,c,d)\in \mathbb R^4 $ is nonzero.
$
M =
\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
a & -b & -c &-d \\
b & a & -d & c \\
c &d &a &-b \\
d&-c&b&a
\end{array} } \right)
$.

Is det$(M)$ non-zero?

Comment: you sure you have the minus signs correct?

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks, I edited it.

Comment: "$(a,b,c,d)\in \mathbb R^4 $ is nonzero", do you mean different from the zero vector (i.e. not all components 0), or no variable 0 at all?

Comment: Still missing a minus in the second row, last column?

Comment: @StackTD I mean at least one of the components is nonzero.

Comment: this might follow one of these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations   need to check indicated $i,j,k$ matrices from the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked, the way it is typed now agrees with $a (id) + b i + c j + d k$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations so the determinant is
$$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2  $$
and is nonzero if any of the (real) entries is nonzero

[image]

The description as SU2, meaning
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\alpha & \beta \\
- \bar{\beta} & \bar{\alpha}
\end{array}
\right)
$$
fits with the other (out of 48 possible) set of four matrices on wikipedia,
[image]

Comment: Is there any way to show that the det agree with its complex form (as an element in SU(2)?

Comment: @user, SU2 fits better with a different set of 4 by 4 matrices. Edited in.